# Can't understand value error try

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please explain how this code is working for me?
I don't understand it from the try command down.
This while loop is working for me. However I do not understand how all of it works.

```
price = 110 #this i get
ttt = 1 #this i get

while price< 0 or price> 100: #this i get
    if ttt >=2: #this i get
        print "This is an invalid entry" #this i get
        print "Please enter a number between 0 and 100" #this i get
    try: #From here i do not understand , but without it, it does not work
          price= int(raw_input("Please enter the price : "))
    except ValueError:
      price = -1   
    ttt +=1
```

As I'm a learner I don't really want a more complicated way to do it.
I just want to fully understand what's happening in the loop.

Comment: You don't understand what `try...except` does? Or what the line below it does?

Comment: yes from try down i dont understand

Comment: *sigh* Does that mean that you understand what `price= int(raw_input("Please enter the price : "))` means?

Comment: @Juhana, I think the OP is just saying that he does not understand what the `try` `except` blocks mean ^.^

Comment: yes thats right Matt, but now i do thanks to the all the anwsers.

Comment: Why is there a Python tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A try statement is a way to catch you code before it *crashes*, or exits do to an uncaught exception. Some functions may throw errors that can cause an application to crash/force quit, and the try block takes thoses would-be-errors, and lets you do something about it.

i.e. -> An app that is trying to open a log file, but no file is found...

> UnCaught: Force-quite, IOException.
>   Caught: Execute another block of code that creates the file.

In your example, it will take raw data from the prompt, and assign it to an integer value... however `abc` can not be converted to an integer, so it would normally crash... Inside of a TRY block, it will return a -1, saying that it did not recieve a result that it was expecting.

Comment: Always happy to help ^.^ Be sure to mark answers as `accepted` if they help you :)

Comment: Not sure that *crashes* is the right term here. Python does *not* crash, it exits explicitly because there was an unhandled exception. A core dump it is not!

Answer (score 2):

`try:` starts a block of code where exceptions can be handled. The `except ValueError` clause means that if anything *throws* the `ValueError` exception in the block, then that exception will be caught and handled by the code under `except`.

In this case that means that if someone enters a value that is *not* a valid integer, `price` will be set to `-1`.

Because `price` is now set to `-1`, the while loop asks for a price again (`-1 < 0` is `True`):

```
while price< 0 or price> 100:  # price was set to -1, so the while loop condition is True.
```

Here is a short demonstration of how the exception would disrupt the program otherwise:

```
>>> int('not an integer')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not an integer'
>>> try:
...     int('not an integer')
... except ValueError:
...     print 'Caught the exception, no problemo!'
... 
Caught the exception, no problemo!
>>> try:
...     price = int('not an integer')
... except ValueError:
...     price = -1
... 
>>> price
-1
```

See the [Python tutorial on exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more information on how this works.

Comment: why does the price need to be -1

Comment: @miguel In case of wrong input, -1 acts as a flag value (to signal incorrect input)

Comment: I mean it does not work if i enter text it crashes

Comment: @miguel: How does it crash? Your code works for me.

Comment: It crashes without the try bit and value error if text is entered but with your explanations i now understand , Thanks

Comment: @miguel: It raises an exception that is not caught, so Python exits, yes. :-) That's what `try:`, `except:` handling is for!

Comment: @AshRj, yes `-1` is used to indicate an error, but other values would be possible. A unifying theme is that `0` is success and everything else is a failure. This comes (at least) from  C, a language that did not have exceptions, and had to resort to some other means of error signaling. In this case, `-1` is used, but `101` would be a of equal utility in this case.

Comment: @AshRj: `-1` is just a convenient value for the `while` loop to continue asking for another value. `price = 101` would also have worked.

Comment: Yes, i understood that. But it could serve as a flag value as price logically should not be negative. Although its not really needed as much in Python as it is in C.

Comment: @AshRj, here's how I would probably do it: https://gist.github.com/4429015. No real need for flag values, when you have some suitable predefined exceptions.

Comment: I am not too comfortable with exceptions, so it isnt the first thing that comes to my  mind. @miku Yes, that is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `try ... except` handles exceptions. Exception handling is a broad topic, for python you can read more about it here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

In your case, input is taken from the user:

```
raw_input("Please enter the price : ")
```

and it is converted to an integer:

```
int(...)
```

Now what happens, when the user inputs "Happy New Year"? It's not a number, it is a wrong value, it a `ValueError`. The function [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) [**raises**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) an [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError), when it cannot produce a result.

If that condition would not be *handled*, the program would stop right there. Instead of just quitting, you can wrap the critical section into a [`try`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) statement and specify, what you want to happen, if an exception occurs. In you case, price is just set to -1:

```
price = -1
```

In the end it should be ensured, that the user inputs a `price` between 0 and 100, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Miku i will read that

Comment: `while price< 0` will evaluate to True and the while loop will run when price = -1